# Is possible to know the size of a stream without using a terminal operation

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have 3 interfaces

```
public interface IGhOrg {
    int getId();

    String getLogin();

    String getName();

    String getLocation();

    Stream<IGhRepo> getRepos();
}

public interface IGhRepo {
    int getId();

    int getSize();

    int getWatchersCount();

    String getLanguage();

    Stream<IGhUser> getContributors();
}

public interface IGhUser {
    int getId();

    String getLogin();

    String getName();

    String getCompany();

    Stream<IGhOrg> getOrgs();
}
```

and I need to implement `Optional<IGhRepo> highestContributors(Stream<IGhOrg> organizations)`

this method returns a IGhRepo with most Contributors(getContributors())

I tried this

```
Optional<IGhRepo> highestContributors(Stream<IGhOrg> organizations){
    return organizations
            .flatMap(IGhOrg::getRepos)
            .max((repo1,repo2)-> (int)repo1.getContributors().count() - (int)repo2.getContributors().count() );
}
```

but it gives me the

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

I understand that count() is a terminal operation in Stream but I can't solve this problem, please help!

thanks

Comment: It seems as if `getContributors()` does not return a new stream, but it is impossible to say without knowing the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify this, but it looks like some or possibly all of the interface methods that return `Stream<...>` values don't return a fresh stream each time they are called.

This seems problematic to me from an API point of view, as it means each of these streams, and a fair chunk of the object's functionality can be used at most once.

You may be able to solve the particular problem you are having by ensuring that the stream from each object is used only once in the method, something like this:

```
Optional<IGhRepo> highestContributors(Stream<IGhOrg> organizations) {
  return organizations
      .flatMap(IGhOrg::getRepos)
      .distinct()
      .map(repo -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(repo, repo.getContributors().count()))
      .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
      .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
}
```

Unfortunately it looks like you will now be stuck if you want to (for example) print a list of the contributors, as the stream returned from `getContributors()` for the returned `IGhRepo` has already been consumed.

You might want to consider having your implementation objects return a fresh stream each time a stream returning method is called.

Answer (score 6):

> Is possible to know the size of a stream without using a terminal operation

No it's not, because streams can be infinite or generate output on demand. It's not necessary that they are backed by collections.

> but it gives me the

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

That's becase you are returning the same stream instance on each method invocation. You should return a new Stream instead.

> I understand that count() is a terminal operation in Stream but I can't solve this problem, please help!

IMHO you are misusing the streams here. Performance and simplicity wise it's much better that you return some `Collection<XXX>` instead of `Stream<XXX>`

Answer (score 4):

**NO.**

This is not possible to know the size of a stream in `java`.

As mentioned in [java 8 stream docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

> No storage. A stream is not a data structure that stores elements;
>   instead, it conveys elements from a source such as a data structure,
>   an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel, through a pipeline
>   of computational operations.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a counter that is incremented per "iteration" using `peek`. In the example below the counter is incremented before every item is processed with `doSomeLogic`

```
final var counter = new AtomicInteger();
getStream().peek(item -> counter.incrementAndGet()).forEach(this::doSomeLogic);
```

Comment: I guess one would only use `peek` for debugging purpose as mentioned by Java docs. Must avoid this for prod environments.