# How to log a message if a stream is empty within the Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given the following Java 8 Stream:

```java
scheduleService.list().stream()
                      .filter(Schedule::getEnabled)
                      .filter(this::runnable)
                      .flatMap(s -> s.getJobs().stream())
                      // .doSomethingArbitrary(System.out.println("A single message. The total number of 
                      // elements in the stream after filtering is " + this::count))
                      .forEach(this::invoke);
```

After the filtering has been applied to the stream and after the first terminal operation has been applied, I would like to either log a debug message if the stream is empty or if it isn't, call the `invoke` method on each element in the stream. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by *after the first terminal operation has been applied*? There is only one terminal operation in the above stream i.e. `forEach`. How about a Java7 code corresponding to what your desired task is? Would make things much clear imho.

Comment: @Naman I have modified my example code. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @crmepham no it does not. what we are confused of is this _after the first terminal operation_ - since there is a single terminal operation... It seems to me that what you are trying to explain here is: if the Stream is empty _after_ that `filter` - you want to log a message; otherwise you want to process all jobs from `s.getJobs().stream() ` by calling the invoke method; if so simply:

Comment: `List<Some> list = scheduleService.list()
                      .stream()
                      .filter(Schedule::getEnabled)
                      .filter(this::runnable)
                      .flatMap(s -> s.getJobs().stream())
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

       if(list.isEmpty()) {log that message;} else {process via invoke}`

Comment: Totally agree with @Eugene. That's the cleanest solution. No matter what else you try, it won't be as clean as what he suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) (here called `StreamInterceptor`), even though this does not really fit the purpose of a collector.

---

### What will the custom collector do?

1. Convert the `Stream<T>` to a `List<T>`
2. Call the Consumer<List>, which will in your case print the length of the list.
3. Return a new `Stream<T>` of the `List<T>`

### Main method

Here I've just broken down your problem into the filtering of a simple  string list and printing them to the console at the end.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myList = List.of("first", "second", "third");
        myList.stream()
                .filter(string -> !string.equals("second"))
                .collect(printCount())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a StreamInterceptor, which will print the length of the stream 
     */
    private static <T> StreamInterceptor<T> printCount() {
        Consumer<List<T>> listSizePrinter = list -> System.out.println("Stream has " + list.size() + " elements");
        return new StreamInterceptor<>(listSizePrinter);
    }
```

When initializing the `StreamInterceptor` you can define a Consumer, that takes in the intermediate list constructed from the stream and performs some action on it. In your case it will just print the size of the list.

### New `StreamInterceptor` class

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class StreamInterceptor<T> implements Collector<T, List<T>, Stream<T>> {

    private final Consumer<List<T>> listConsumer;

    public StreamInterceptor(Consumer<List<T>> listConsumer) {
        this.listConsumer = listConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<T>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return List::add;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<T>> combiner() {
        return (list1, list2) -> {
            list1.addAll(list2);
            return list1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<T>, Stream<T>> finisher() {
        return list -> {
            listConsumer.accept(list);
            return list.stream();
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

### Resources

- [How to create a custom Collector](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors)
- [Why do we need to convert the Stream to a List first to know its size?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42553105/18931874)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `Stream` into a custom method like the following

```
Stream<???> stream = scheduleService.list().stream()
                                           .filter(Schedule::getEnabled)
                                           .filter(this::runnable)
                                           .flatMap(s -> s.getJobs().stream());

forEachOrElse(stream, this::invoke, () -> System.out.println("The stream was empty"));
```

With `forEachOrElse` being

```
public <T> void forEachOrElse(Stream<T> inStream, Consumer<T> consumer, Runnable orElse) {
    AtomicBoolean wasEmpty = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    inStream.forEach(e -> {
        wasEmpty.set(false);
        consumer.accept(e);
    });

    if (wasEmpty.get())
        orElse.run();
}
```

<sub>I can't test it right now but it should do its magic</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really "nice" at all, but you could use peek to look into your stream and set an AtomicBoolean:

```
AtomicBoolean empty = new AtomicBoolean(true);

scheduleService.list().stream()
                      .filter(Schedule::getEnabled)
                      .filter(this::runnable)
                      .flatMap(s -> s.getJobs().stream())
                      .peek(s -> ab.set(false);)
                      .forEach(this::invoke);

if(empty.get()){
   // is Empty
}
```

Comment: How is this setting the `empty` boolean to true if the stream is empty?

Comment: The boolean is true at start. but if any job exists, it will set it to false and then if the boolean is set to true, the log will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `peek` before converting the list to `stream`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(4, 5), Collections.emptyList())
            .filter(x -> x.size() % 2 == 0)
            .peek(s -> System.out.println(s.isEmpty()))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output**

```
false
4
5
true
```