# How to get size of stream and return the original stream in java8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to do something like below:

```
Stream<Student> allStudent=studentRepo.findAll()

long count=allStudent.count();
```

then

```
return allStudent
```

But problem : `count()` is an terminal operation and after that i am not able to return the stream.

The reason for doing this is to stream all student record over Kafka and at the same time send the record count to the consumer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044849/is-possible-to-know-the-size-of-a-stream-without-using-a-terminal-operation

Comment: Why do you need this? For pagination?

Comment: I am streaming this all student record over kafka and want to send the record count to the consumer.

Comment: I suggest you also put the code streaming to kafka and how you sending the count to consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the stream has `SIZED` characteristic, you can use the size from the spliterator object:

```java
Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
long count = spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown();
...
return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, stream.isParallel());
```

But if `getExactSizeIfKnown` returns `-1` - eigher try to save the stream to an intermediate collection, get size and then use the `stream()` method to return the data, or think of something else.

Comment: English man... [English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684)

Comment: @NicoVanBelle sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Count using `peek()` to a list then stream that:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
allStudent = allStudent
    .peek(o -> i.incrementAndGet())
    .collect(toList())
    .stream();

// do something with count

return allStudent;
```

Or more mundane:

```
List<Student> students = allStudent.stream().collect(toList());
long count = students.size();
return students.stream();
```